# Indefinite integration.

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

> Integrate :- $\displaystyle\int\dfrac{2x^2}{2x\cos(2x)+(x^2-1)\sin(2x)}$

I tried dividing by $\cos^2(x)$ and then substituting $\tan(x)=t$.

Comment: Why do you ask about the same integral repeatedly ?

Comment: Wrong answers on that thread

Comment: Ok but better don't close this thread

Comment: Two answers on that thread

Comment: 1) directly representing it as a differential of the answer to be found 2) completely incorrect